# Getting errors while trying to open files on emu8086

Tags: file, assembly, emu8086

I'm trying to test my code on emu, but the problem is that I get errors.

```
open_files:
    lea dx, filename_asm
    mov ah, 3Dh     ; 3Dh - opening the file
    mov al, 00h     ; 00h - reading
    int 21h

    mov handle_asm, ax
    jc fopen_error

    lea dx, filename_htm
    xor ax, ax
    mov ah, 3Ch     ; 3dh - making of the file or clearing it
    mov cx, 00h     ; 00h - normal
    int 21h

    mov handle_htm, ax
    jc fopen_error  

    jmp html_1

fopen_error:
    lea dx, show_error_msg
    mov ah, 09h 
    int 21h       

    call exit_pro

html_1:
    call write_html_1
```

I get error "interrupt error: 21h/3Dh : cannot open file.".

What I've been reading is that I need to put the code txt file in the emu8086 vdrive C folder, which I've done. I'm trying to set command line arguments as " c:\ antra.exe antra.asm antra.htm". Should I specify the path or something?

Comment: Can you just create some empty file + close it, so it should be somewhere on emu vdrive, and check where it is created? Maybe you have problem with "current working directory" (`int 21h,3B`)? Or try to provide full emulated path, so it will not need current dir set. ... Actually there's of course [`int 21h,47`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-47.html) get current directory, put it at the start of code and run it in debugger, to see what it returns.

Comment: Find the directory where EMU was installed, inside you will find many subdirectories, your files are created inside "MyBuild", you can give more permissions to EMU directory and subdirectories.